# Share C variable with Javascript on an Arduino

Tags: javascript, c, arduino

I'm programming a simple web server on an Arduino. I basically send HTML, CSS and Javascript to a client through a method in C code. Now I've come to need a C variable in a Javascript if-case, and I need to do it without using ASP.NET.

```
client.println("if (%c == 1) {",stat[0]);
```

I tried changing the data type, I tried using a Java-style with plus signs, I even tried storing it in a string first and then sending it in; nothing works.

stat[0] is declared and changes over time.

The error I get from the compiler:

*Webserver4.cpp:217:40: error: call of overloaded 'println(const char [15], byte&)' is ambiguous
C:\mpide-0023-windows-20111221\hardware\pic32\cores\pic32/Print.h:66:7: note: candidates are: void Print::println(char, int)* 
(...)

Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't this be `if (%c == 1)`?

Comment: True, though the compiling errors don't notice Javascript errors -- but you're entirely correct and I'll change it. :)

Comment: I've changed the question to `==`. Arguably, though, since this is Javascript it would be better to be `===`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation problem is due to the `printXxx()` functions available on the `client` object not supporting `printf` format specifiers. Whilst it's not obvious what the type of `client` is, it evidently subclasses the built-in Arduino [`Print`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h) class.

To use the format specifiers you have to do it in two steps, for example (note that a `byte` in Arduino is actually a `uint8_t` and `PRIu8` is the format specifier for this type):

```
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS 1
#include <inttypes.h>

// ...

char ifStatement[13];
sprintf(ifStatement, "if (%" PRIu8 " == 1) {", stat[0]);
client.println(ifStatement);

client.println("// JavaScript code to execute if stat[0] == 1");

client.println("}");
```

Also, note that this assumes that `stat[0]` is always a single digit. If it has two or more digits the `ifStatement` buffer will overflow, corrupting memory.

However, since ([as unwind points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10495196/4023)) the JavaScript if statement is essentially constant from the perspective of the browser, it would perhaps be simpler to do this in the Arduino code:

```
if (stat[0] == 1) {
    client.println("// JavaScript code to execute if stat[0] == 1");
}
```

Comment: Stat[0] is always either a 1 or a 0. I essentially want different parts of the Javascript code to run depending on what stat[0] is; and what it is will change from time to time. If I use your second suggestion, it means that any change in stat[0] won't be registered when the site is refreshed, correct?

It shouldn't remain constant since I can print: "client.println(stat[0]);" directly onto the webpage. All of this is encased in a method that creates a client connection.


So I'll try your first idea out later, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I had assumed that refreshing the site would cause the Arduion code to regenerate the JavaScript code, in which case changes to `stat[0]` will be registered. If that's not true I'll update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The compiler complains about a lack of a parenthesis before PRIu8.
"error: expected ')' before 'PRIu8'" Any ideas? :)

Comment: Ah, in the documentation (http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__inttypes.html) it says that you must `#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` before `#include <inttypes.h>`. I've updated the answer with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter has noted, it should probably be `if (%c == 1)` in the emitted Javascript code.

Also, note that the expression you're emitting is constant, so you could just as well re-factor your C code to emit the proper code (the code that is taken if the `if` evaluates to true) directly, and reduce the complexity of the emitted code.

You're not showing the C declaration of `stat`, which makes it hard to be sure you're doing it right. For the `%c` formatting code, and the array indexing, it should be an array of characters, which is a bit odd since the code you're emitting is comparing against an integer.

Comment: There's a bit of an issue with using If-cases directly with C-code, if that's what you mean. Stat is an array declared as a byte (I tried %b), and stat[0] is either 0 or 1.